# Scrolling Effect (Fast and Slow)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to show effect like scrolling.
In iphone Scrolling, when the user touch fast, then the scroll fast.
And also the user touch slowly , then the scroll slow.
I want to get scroll value and want to input it to my rotate function.
Have you any good idea to implement this?
Need Help.
Best.

Comment: Where you want to apply this scrolling effect? In which UI control?

Comment: I want to rotate six circles around center point more smoothly.

Comment: And the circles are ccsprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use the touchEvents and calculate how far the finger has moved. This will tell you how fast you should scroll.

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```